# Byte of word returns one less than what it should be

Tags: c++, strlen, strcat

My professor is having us make our own version of the functions mystrcat, mystrlen and mystrcopy. I have a problem where the word is returning the wrong amount of bytes. Or, rather, I think it is.

The phrase: `"HELLO WORLD!"` , if I am not wrong, should return 13 bytes? Like in:

```
const char char_literal[] =
   { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', 'W', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D', '!', '\0' };
  //  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13
```

I wrote the function `myStrLen()` that returns (`{ 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' '}`) as `6`, but because it is alone, there should be a `'\0'` at the end right?
So should I be returning `i + 1` or is `6` correct?

```
int myStrLen(char stringInput[]){
    for(int i = 0; ; i++){
        if(stringInput[i] == '\0'){
            return i;
```

Comment: _"So should I be returning i + 1 or is 6 correct?"_ Totally depends on how to use `i` or `i + 1` further.

Comment: What is your expectation for `myStrLen("")` ? 0 or 1 ?

Comment: `strlen()` doesn't count the null terminator.

Comment: Tell your professor he should be teaching `std::string`.

Comment: @Ron I'd support that!

Comment: Disagree. The instructor should be honest about teaching C.

Comment: No need to ask us. You could simply compare your results against the value returned by the actual `strlen()`.  Or, even better, [read the manual for `strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: @user4581301 Well, if they claim to teach c++ (and most of them seem to do) :-P ...

Comment: @TheDude They're teaching computer science *using* C++. Are you claiming that you can't use a high-level language when teaching low-level concepts?

Comment: @TheDude I am just passing a word through the function and having it return it's size as strlen would if you used it as a function.

Comment: @user4581301 Haha, nice one. So true.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would expect 0 since it is empty, but I could potentially see 1 as it still holds null?

Comment: @Barmar _"Are you claiming that you can't use a high-level language when teaching low-level concepts?"_ No, but _"low level concepts"_ belong to the _advanced classes' stuff_, not the _beginner class_ ones.

Comment: @Barmar AHH, I understand. So when I declared my word size as a const int, it accounts for the null; however, thats just for the size and not for strlen

Comment: Are you learning about C++ or "C with classes"?

Comment: The official answer, according to the syllabus is C++. I am in my second semester, so the class above intro

Comment: Supplement your formal education with these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is a world of joy. It's just the academia didn't get the memo yet.

Comment: I think these C++ courses taught in this manner are designed for students to turn to Java or Python instead of C++.

Comment: @Vincent I'm not sure what you mean by word size. If you're talking about the `sizeof` operator, it doesn't tell you the string length, it tells you how much memory is used for the whole variable or array. That includes the null terminaor, and padding bytes in other data types.

Comment: @Vincent Well, if you insist using raw arrays/c-style character literals as it's a requirement not to fail that class: What are you considering a _"word"_? Should that word include the whitespace character or not. Should the determined string length be `0` if there are only whitespaces? Should the `'\0'` counted? How will you use the result of your function?

Comment: Sounds to me like a decent time to teach C++'s C-like underbelly. You need to know this stuff in order to survive the coming Algorithms and Data Structures course.  Assuming this isn't the Algorithms and Data Structures course. If it is, draw the linked list before you start coding. Seriously. Pencil and paper. Save you tonnes of debugging.

Comment: You should make the signature of your version the same as `strlen` (at least that would be IMO a good start). i.e. `size_t myStrlen(const char* str);`

Comment: @user4581301 I bet a cup of coffee that one of the next requirements will be "you cannot use std::string".

Comment: So what I did was just run it against the function I am trying to recreate with my own code as the assignment states and it seems to match. If you guys are confused on my word, im sorry. Thanks for the help! Here is the source code I was referring to. https://pastebin.com/sTBzmFjY

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not going to take that bet, but if the goal of the assignment is to teach how to make a `std::string` the restriction makes sense. Otherwise... Meh. But I try to save my disrespect for "Welcome to CS101. First class, so let's do POINTERS!" I'm a teach logic first kinda guy.

Comment: @Vincent I got confused first when you mentioned words. I'd recommend not to call strings of characters in a programming context "word", since "word" refers to the natural unit of data in a particular processor architecture. The word size is what is refered to by 32bit or 64bit architecture. On a 32-bit system a word is 4 bytes. It has nothing to do with strings. Just say "string".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your professor tells you to write a function that behaves exactly as [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen), then it shall not count the string termination character:

> **std::size_t strlen( const char* str );**
>
> Returns the length of the given byte string, that is, the number of
>   characters in a character array whose first element is pointed to by
>   str up to and not including the first null character. ...

So returning `i` is correct, besides the fact that the "original" `strlen` takes a const input parameter and returns a `size_t`...